# When the xutility error occured what I have to do

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2019

I want to make the program that counts the number of each digit of some number.
The number is multiple of three integer input from console. I convert the number to string for counting and used count function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    int multi = a * b * c;
    string str_multi = to_string(multi);
    for (int a = 0; a <= 9;a++) {
        char* tmp;
        _itoa_s(a, tmp,2, 10);
        cout << count(str_multi.begin(), str_multi.end(), tmp) << endl;
    }
}
```

And I get the errorcode C2446.
The error saying,"'==':Not converted from 'const_TY' to 'int'"
This error was in the xutility file. I think the problem is count function or
_iota_s function but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: "I convert the number to string for counting" - Why would you do that? A string is terrible for counting things. You want an integer for counting.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter to `std::count` needs to be a `char` in this case (or be convertible to a char), so just change your loop to:

```
for (int a = '0'; a <= '9'; a++) {
   cout << count(str_multi.begin(), str_multi.end(), a) << endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ywhItsULhsX6WjCe)